# Chrome Browser run twice during specifying the file to be downloaded using Selenium Webdriver c# Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am running my test case on 2 different browser "Chrome" and "Firefox".I am trying specified the path of my file to be downloaded during the [test] is running for "Chrome". All the code work as expected, I am able to save my file in the specified path. My "Firefox" is working fine but not for "Chrome". It just that every time when I run my script,it will open 2 "Chrome" browser , ( (1st) just open and do nothing ) , (2nd)(run the script as expected)). So on every test case i run , it will run all the test case on the 2nd "Chrome" browser.Furthermore, I couldnt use the [TearDown] method to close the browser, because it run on the 2nd "Chrome" browser , instead of the 1st "Chrome

```
 [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]



public class Program<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()

{
    IWebDriver driver;
    IWebElement element;

    [SetUp]
    public void StartBrowser1()
    {

        driver = new TWebDriver();

        ICapabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
        string browserName = string.Empty;
        if (caps.HasCapability("browserName"))
        {
            browserName = caps.GetCapability("browserName").ToString();

            if (browserName.Equals("chrome"))
            {
                String myDownloadFolder = @"c:\temp\GoogleChrome\";
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", myDownloadFolder);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            }


            }
            // For firefox 
            else if (browserName.Equals("firefox"))
            {
                String myDownloadFolder = @"c:\temp\MozillaFirefox\";
                FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
                fp.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
                fp.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", myDownloadFolder);
                fp.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
                // disable Firefox's built-in PDF viewer
                fp.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);}

                Base.Login(driver);  //  base class , the code for the base class

                /* public static void Login(IWebDriver driver)
                 {
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.163.0.1/admin/Login/Login.aspx");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtUserID")).SendKeys("abc");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_txtPassword")).SendKeys("123456");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ucLogin_cmdLogin")).Click();
                }
                */
            }                                                    


[TearDown]
    public void CloseBrowser()
    {
        Base.Logout(driver);
    }
```

Comment: You call `driver = new TWebDriver();` and `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` if `browserName.Equals("chrome")`. That's probably why you have 2 browsers open.

Comment: @Ardesco , yeah actually i saw my code and i knew because of these driver = new TWebDriver(); and driver = new ChromeDriver(options) it open twice, but is there anywhere the file will be save in the Specified location mentioned in and not run the "Chrome" twice. I tried many methods, Chrome will have to run twice in order for the file to be able to save to that location, when the test  run on "Chrome".